# Unity2D rigidbody2D.velocity on Android Device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a 2D game where I need to move the players rigidbody2D in the x axis when the device is tilted. The code I have below is what I believe should work, but it doesn't. The player doesn't move at all. What am I doing wrong and why?

```
Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
        dir.x = Input.acceleration.y;
        if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
            dir.Normalize();

        dir *= Time.deltaTime;
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(dir.x));
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (dir.x * tiltSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
```

Full code below

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterControllerScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float maxSpeed = 10f;
bool facingRight = true;
public float tiltSpeed = 10f;

Animator anim;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    // Set animation
    if ((Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.Android) || (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)){
        float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        // Decide what way animation moving
        if (move > 0 && !facingRight)
            Flip ();
        else if (move < 0 && facingRight)
            Flip ();
    }
    else {
        Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
        dir.x = Input.acceleration.y;
        if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
            dir.Normalize();

        dir *= Time.deltaTime;
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(dir.x));
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (dir.x * tiltSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        // Decide what way animation moving
        if (move > 0 && !facingRight)
            Flip ();
        else if (move < 0 && facingRight)
            Flip ();
    }
}

void Flip () {
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 thescale = transform.localScale;
    thescale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = thescale;
}
}
```

Comment: Same code, same issue, I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer is still useful for you since you posted a few month ago

I think your code will always go through the first if case. You should replace

```
(Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.Android) || (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
```

by

```
(Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.Android) && (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
```

Since they can't be true both at the same time